# Structure program showing array type has incomplete element type

Tags: c, struct

I am writing simple array program.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct Student
{
   int  i;  //Stores address of integer Variable
   char *name; //Stores address of Character String
};

int main()
{
struct student s1[] ={
                        {1,"srini"},
                        {2,"pankaj"},
                        {3,"rajini"}
                      };

printf("\nRoll Number of Student : %d",s1.i);
printf("\nName of Student        : %s",s1.name[0]);

return(0);
}
```

Showing error as 
**error: array type has incomplete element type**

I dont know what I am doing wrong

Comment: `student` - capital or not?

Comment: You might want to check out [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 4):

1. C is case-sensitive. You define `Student` as the `struct` but then use `student` in the function body.
2. `s1` is an *array* of `Student`s. To access each element you'll need `s1[index]`, followed by the member selection operator `.`. Here `index` is 0, 1, or 2.
3. Consider using a `const char*` as the name: this emphasises the fact that you cannot change the read-only string literals.

Comment: silly mistake from me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`s1` is an array.

So you should do

```
printf("\nRoll Number of Student : %d",s1[0].i);
printf("\nName of Student        : %s",s1[0].name);
```